# Prove norm does not come from inner product.

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

[image]

I know I have to show it does not satisfy the parallelogram law but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the method described in the answer to your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1285780/81360).  In particular, take $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$.